# GPO Has No Power but All Breakers Are On

Tags: electrical, troubleshooting

Have a weird one. I have three power points at opposite ends of the house that are on the same breaker. Randomly tonight power went out to them. All breakers are turned on and all other outlets work fine; the only issue is those three outlets. Why would they not work when all switches are on?

Comment: Loose connection?

Comment: I have checked the back of the outlets no loose wires.

Comment: If the breakers are on and you don't have power, either there's a wiring problem or something is wrong with the PowerPoints.

Comment: Are all 3 legs dead or possibly just 1. A blown fuse can cause this on the utility supply.  Measuring L1-l2, L2-l3, l1-l3 should all have similar voltages if 1 measurement is bad a fuse on the pole is likely

Comment: what is meant by, "Randomly tonight power went out to them"?

Comment: What does the multimeter show?

Answer (score -1):

There may be more than just the three outlets and one has the Ground Fault Interrupt tripped.

Comment: This isn't really formatted as an answer.  This would be more appropriate as a comment.